# chrome.scripting.executeScript Refused to connect to 'http://xyz' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to execute an `HTML POST` request from `background.js` and get the response to treat it with local methods.

The `POST` request works as long as I'm in an `isolated world`, but it never reaches the line, that is supposed to execute after the script

```
console.log('script returned:', response);
```

In addition, the methods I declared in `background.js` are not reachable in the callback `onreadystatechange` (eg. `onPostSuccess`)

So I changed the `world` param to '`MAIN`', and now I get the following error:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:5173/cv/submit' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' blob: wss: *.licdn.com *.linkedin.com *.lynda.com linkedin.sc.omtrdc.net/b/ss/ cdn.linkedin.oribi.io *.data.digitalassistant.oci.oraclecloud.com/chat/ *.tealiumiq.com *.microsoft.com *.office.com *.skype.com *.skype.net *.agora.io:* *.sd-rtn.com:* *.qualtrics.com *.trouter.io dpm.demdex.net/id lnkd.demdex.net".
```

Here's my code.

```
async function submitResume(tabId, jsonData) {
    console.log("executing script with args: data: ", jsonData)

    // Pass URL and JSON data as parameters to content script
    const response = await chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
            target: {tabId},
            func: postJson,
            args: [POST_CV_URL, jsonData],
            world: "MAIN"
        }
    );

    console.log('script returned:', response);

    // Handle response
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        // Request failed
        console.error('Failed to execute content script:', chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
        // Request successful
        console.log('Content script executed successfully');
    }
}

function postJson(url, jsonData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
// Create XHR object
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

// Convert JSON data to string and send in the request
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

// Handle response
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    // Request successful
                    console.log('XHR POST request successful:', xhr);
                    //onPostSuccess(xhr.response) throws onPostSuccess is not defined

                    resolve(xhr.responseText)
                } else {
                    // Request failed
                    console.error('XHR POST request failed:', xhr.statusText);
                    reject(new Error('XHR POST request failed:' + xhr.statusText))
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I tried to add this line in my manifest without success: it says the value is invalid

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; connect-src http://localhost:5173; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: executeScript runs the code as a content script, which can't make a cross-origin POST request in modern Chrome (the response is dropped). Why do you use executeScript? You can call `fetch` directly in the background script. Certainly you should avoid world MAIN like plague because the prototypes/globals can be spoofed or broken by the site.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you saved my day with it. It's my first chrome extension, and I find it very hard to find what is allowed in which of the three worlds (content, background and popup), it surely makes sense, but for a newbie it's such a mess. I think there should be at least an exception thrown to warn the developer that he's in a forbidden space. Executing the method and silently not calling back is a very weird approach in my opinion. Maybe I should file a bug about that?

Comment: It's not a bug: when using await you need try{await foo()}catch(e){...} to see the error `e`, not chrome.runtime.lastError.

Comment: Ok thanks again, I thought the code is special, and errors are sent chrome.runtime instead of throwing out. Thank you for you answers. You can put an answer to the question if you want me to mark it as the solution